# How can I put Regex.Matches into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I have multiple Regex Matches. How can I put them into an array and call them each individually, for example `ID[0] ID[1]`?

```
string value = ("{\"ID\":\"([A-Za-z0-9_., ]+)\",");
string ID = Regex.Matches(textt, @value);`
```

Comment: Last I heard `Matches()` returned a collection, not a string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do that already, since [**`MatchCollection`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) has an [int indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.item.aspx) that lets you access matches by index. This is perfectly valid:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(textt, @value);
Match firstMatch = matches[0];
```

But if you really want to put the matches into an array, you can do:

```
Match[] matches = Regex.Matches(textt, @value)
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: can you post the vb equivalent for your second code snippet above?

Comment: @Smith Try: Dim matches() As Match = Regex.Matches(textt, @value).Cast(Of Match)().ToArray()

Comment: am using .net 2.0, that cast is not supported there

Comment: @ani why don't i have the cast option in 4.5 ?

Comment: @EliEkstein You need to import the using System.Linq :-)

Answer (score 2):

Or this combo of the last 2 might be a little easier to take in...  A MatchCollection can be used like an array directly - no need for the secondary array:

```
string value = ("{\"ID\":\"([A-Za-z0-9_., ]+)\",");
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(textt, @value);
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Response.Write(matches[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another method

```
  string value = ("{\"ID\":\"([A-Za-z0-9_., ]+)\",");
  MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(textt, @value);

  string[] ID = new string[match.Count];
  for (int i = 0; i < match.Length; i++)
  {
    ID[i] = match[i].Groups[1].Value; // (Index 1 is the first group)
  }
```

Comment: Over-complicated by secondary array.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem of returning a non-strongly-typed `MatchCollection`, there's an additional problem with the `Regex.Matches()` method in **.NET**. Namely, although there's an overload that lets you specify a starting index in the input string, there's no way to limit the character count.

The following extension method solves both problems. It's also considerably simpler than the **.NET** pairing of `Matches()` and `MatchCollection` because it does away with the lazy-evaluation behavior effected by `MatchCollection`, instead returning the complete set of matches all at once.

```
public static Match[] Matches(this Regex rx, String s, int ix, int c)
{
    if ((ix | c) < 0 || ix + c > s.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    int i = 0;
    var rg = Array.Empty<Match>();
    Match m;
    while (c > 0 && (m = rx.Match(s, ix, c)).Success)
    {
        if (i == rg.Length)
            Array.Resize(ref rg, (i | 1) << 1);

        rg[i++] = m;
        c += ix - (ix = m.Index + m.Length);
    }
    if (i < rg.Length)
        Array.Resize(ref rg, i);
    return rg;
}
```