# Split String At Every Non-Letter/Non-Number Character

Tags: c#, regex, string

Imagine a string that contains special characters like $§%%,., numbers and letters.

I want to receive the letter and number junks of an arbitrary string as an array of strings.

A good solution seems to be the use of regex, but I don't know how to express [numbers and letters]

```
// example
"abc" = {"abc"};
"ab .c" = {"ab", "c"}
"ab123,cd2,  ,,%&$§56" = {"ab123", "cd2", "56"}

// try
string input = "jdahs32455$§&%$§df233§$fd";
string[] output = input.Split(Regex("makejunksfromstring"));
```

Comment: by "junks" you meant "chunks" ? Also very difficult to understand what you want. Can you clearly write some example of inputs and their corresponding outputs you are expecting

Comment: I have added more and clearer examples

Comment: @JNevill thanks, but please explain how your regex can respect numbers and letters

Comment: Check out the explanation of what a "word character" is here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter  `\w` matches a word character, `\W` (capital) matches non-word characters

Comment: Since regex.matches returns a collection, do you really want to turn this into an array? Also instead of split, return all matches of `[A-Za-z0-9]+`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4632438/9758194)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *extract* chunks of 1 or more letters/digits you may use

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+   # ASCII only letters/digits
[\p{L}0-9]+    # Any Unicode letters and ASCII only digits 
[\p{L}\p{N}]+  # Any Unicode letters/digits
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cp%7BL%7D0-9%5D%2B&i=abc%0D%0Aab%20.c%0D%0Aab123%2Ccd2%2C%20%20%2C%2C%25%26%24%C2%A756).

[C# usage](https://ideone.com/JkPkyz):

```
string[] output = Regex.Matches(input, @"[\p{L}\p{N}]+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: In the end I was also using the Matching instead of the Split. I did it with [A-Za-z0-9]+ and worked with the match collection. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, regex is indeed a good solution for this.

And in fact, to just match all standard words in the input sequence, this is all you need:

```
(\w+)
```

Let me quickly explain

\w matches any word character and is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] - matching a through z or A through Z or 0-9 or _, you might wanna go with [a-zA-Z0-9] instead to avoid that underscore.

Wrapping an expression in () means that you want to capture that part as a group.

The + means that you want sequences of 1 or more of the preceding characters.

Refer to a regular expression cheat sheet to see all the possibilities, such as
https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Or any that you find online.

Also there are tools available to quickly test out your regular expressions, such as
https://regex101.com/ (quite well visualised matching)
or http://regexstorm.net/tester specifically for .NET

Comment: * spaces should also be counted as "special" characters

Comment: I use ``string s = Regex.Split(s, "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)");`` and it is still using the .,.,